# How to call function in jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
(function($) { 
    $.fn.top_islides = function(){
        var ajax_init = function(){
            init_islides();
            setTimeout(function(){picmove()},300);
        };
//.....
    };  
})(jQuery);
```

call it in doucument ready in another file

```
$('#top_slides').top_islides();
$('#top_slides').top_islides().ajax_init();
```

I thought it should work ,I got an error, what's the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
(function($) {
    //Assuming $.fn.top_islides is defined
    $.fn.top_islides.ajax_init = function(){
        init_islides();
        setTimeout(picmove,300);
    };
 //.....
})(jQuery);
```

Or

```
(function($) { 
    $.fn.top_islides = function(){
        var ajax_init = function(){
            init_islides();
            setTimeout(picmove,300);
        };
        return {
            ajax_init: ajax_init
        };
    });
     //.....
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this as in the example below:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $.someplugin = {
      CallMe : function() {
            alert("You called?");
        },
      otherstuff : function() { alert("other stuff!"); }
    };


    $.someplugin.CallMe();
    $.someplugin.otherstuff();
</script>
```

Comment: I changed to  ajax_init : function(){
   init_islides();
   setTimeout(function(){picmove()},300);
  };  but error say SyntaxError: function statement requires a name

Answer (score 0):

when using `var` inside a function, it will make the element "private". it's a hacky way to make visibility in Javascript work, while true class structure don't come to Javascript.
You need to either set it to the prototype of your function or to return an object

```js
(function($) { 
  $.fn.top_islides = function(){
    var ajax_init = function(){
        init_islides();
        setTimeout(function(){picmove()},300);
    };
    return {
      'ajax_init': ajax_init
    };
  //.....
  };  
 })(jQuery);
```

or

```js
(function($) { 
  $.fn.top_islides = function(){
  //.....
  };
  $.fn.top_islides.prototype.ajax_init = function(){
    init_islides();
    setTimeout(function(){picmove()},300);
  }
 })(jQuery);
```

but in your case, you won't be using prototype, since you aren't instantiating a new `top_islides` object, but accessing through jQuery, so the first option is your best bet.

Comment: can you explain a bit more about 'return', I don't understand, how to call the return value?

Comment: `return` does what it name's meant to be, return something from the function. if you want to return more than one value, you need to use an object, and name each return element. You may return variables, functions or other objects, and you would call it `$('element').top_islides().funct()` or `$('element').top_islides().variable` or an object `$('element').top_islides().obj.property()`

Answer (score 0):

Imo, best solution is used trigger which is cleaner because you can keep the chainable plugin system.

You can declare event handler in your plugin declaration and trigger from outside:

```
(function($) { 
  $.fn.top_islides = function(){
    this.on ('init_islides', function(){
        setTimeout(function(){picmove()},300);
    };
  //.....
  };  
 })(jQuery);
$( "button" ).click(function () {
  $( "p" ).trigger( "init_islides");
});
```

DOC can be found here : http://api.jquery.com/on/